# How to abbreviate row of strings with a multiple character delimiter?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have a table with a column that looks like the below:

```
+----------------+
| name           |
+----------------+
| Tim^*^Abas     |
| Roy^*^Techs    |
| Amanda^*^Futer |
| ...            |
+----------------+
```

It corresponds to first name, last name, with three characters `^*^` joining them.

I want to change this table to abbreviate each name so it takes the first letter of each first name, last name. The final column might look like:

```
+----------------+
| name           |
+----------------+
| T.A.           |
| R.T.           |
| A.F.           |
| ...            |
+----------------+
```

Can this be done strictly in SQL?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...? String functions are highly vendor-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
concat(left(name, 1), '.', substring(name, locate('^*^', name) + 3, 1), '.')
```

If you wanted an `update` query:

```
update mytable
set name = concat(left(name, 1), '.', substring(name, locate('^*^', name) + 3, 1), '.')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use `substring_index()`:

```
concat(left(name, 1), '.', left(substring_index(name, '^*^', -1), 1), '.')
```