# Trim String using a multi-character delimiter

Tags: mysql

Similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64186247/how-to-abbreviate-row-of-strings-with-a-multiple-character-delimiter), I need to edit the value of a column, on several rows of a table, based on the presence of a string (not a single character delimiter) within the value of that column.  Unlike the other solution, I am not trying to replace or add characters, nor am I trying to save data AFTER the string.  In the corrupted data string:

```
good stuff in front'abc d' bad stuff I want to get rid of
```

I need a MySQL statement to find `'abc d'` in the string, and then just return `good stuff in front`.

Comment: Use `LOCATE()` to get the position of the substring, and `LEFT()` to get the portion of the string before that position.

Comment: You can also use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`, with `'\'abc d\''` as the delimiter.

Comment: See [String Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) for all the MySQL string functions. You should be able to find several ways to do it in there.

Comment: @Barmar I have tried several different sql statements prior to posting this question. Your assertion that I am trying to get people to do my job is completely inappropriate and unprofessional.[br][br]Things I have tried:[br]LOCATE -- Only works to locate the string[br]SUBSTRING_INDEX -- Only works, as far as I can tell, on single-character delimiters[br]SUBSTR -- Doesn't work, because the string before and after the substring located, is of random length[br]TRIM (TRAILING) -- Would work if I could use a wildcard afterwards.

Comment: You use LOCATE and LEFT together. SUBSTRING_INDEX is not limited to a 1-character delimiter.

Comment: You say you're not asking someone else to do it for you. But I don't know how to answer the question without doing it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUBSTRING_INDEX()` can do this.

```
select substring_index("good stuff in front'abc d' bad stuff I want to get rid of", "'abc d'", 1);
```

You can also combine `LOCATE()` and `LEFT()`:

```
select LEFT("good stuff in front'abc d' bad stuff I want to get rid of", LOCATE("'abc d'", "good stuff in front'abc d' bad stuff I want to get rid of")-1);
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  It turns out I was looking for the wrong delimiter-string, which is why I kept getting 0 results.  To extend my fictitious example, the delimiter-string I wanted to get rid of did not start with the letter 'a', I was able to do a SUBSTRING_INDEX on the corrupted column, by finding the substring 'bc d' (spaces _were_ found, much to my delight).  I also added a WHERE clause and used LOCATE, so that I would limit the update to rows that had the substring 'bc d'.

`UPDATE table
SET bad_column=SUBSTRING_INDEX(bad_column, 'bc d', 1)
WHERE LOCATE('bc d', bad_column)>0`